# prove that a non constant linear functional from a normed linear space X is discontinuous if and only if Z(f) = {x in X | f(x) = 0} is dense in X.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I could prove that if Z(f) is dense in X then the functional must me discontinuous but I am not able to prove the other way round

Comment: this question is asked many times on the site.

Comment: can you send me the link with an answer?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123282/linear-functional-on-a-banach-space-is-discontinuous-then-its-nullspace-is-dense

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1432705/f-is-discontinuous-iff-kernelf-is-dense-in-x for both directions