# Example of a non-closed subspace such that the quotient is not a Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, examples-counterexamples, normed-spaces

As I've learnt recently in my Functional Analysis course, it is well known that if $X$ is a normed Banach space and $Y$ is a closed subspace, then the quotient $X/Y$ is a Banach space (e.g. [How to show that quotient space $X/Y$ is complete when $X$ is Banach space, and $Y$ is a closed subspace of $X$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319867/how-to-show-that-quotient-space-x-y-is-complete-when-x-is-banach-space-and))

However, I've been trying to find an explicit example of a normed Banach space $X$ and a non-closed subspace $Y$ such that $X/Y$ is not a Banach space, but I haven't come to something yet.

Can you help me to find such spaces?
It would be great to read your answers, there may be some interesting examples out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $\alpha\colon X\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ be a discontinuous linear form. Then $\ker\alpha$ is a dense subspace of $X$. And $X/\ker\alpha$ is not a Banach space simply because the norm$$\|x+\ker\alpha\|=\inf\{\|x+y\|\,|\,y\in\ker\alpha\}$$is not a norm. In fact, it follows from the density of $\ker\alpha$ that$$(\forall x\in X):\|x+\ker\alpha\|=0.$$

Comment: I see, great! For the sake of completeness, there are some examples of discontinous linear forms on Banach spaces https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99206/discontinuous-linear-functional Also, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1432705/f-is-discontinuous-iff-kernelf-is-dense-in-x

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to "find" examples, *any* non-closed subspace gives an example.

Say $Y$ is a subspace of $X$ and $Y$ is not closed. Say $y_n\in Y$, $y_n\to  x$ and $x\notin Y$. Then $$||x+Y||=0$$although  $x+Y\ne0$.